# Can't delete/ stop job in dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a cluster via API (lets name it **my_project/clusterUuid123**) and submitted a job. Right after job submission, the cluster got deleted but the job is still "running". If I try to delete the job (via api, shell, ui) it throws an error "... **cluster not found project/clusterUuid123**.

```
{
"code": 404,
"message": "Cluster not found "my_project/clusterUuid123",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Recreating the cluster won't solve the problem. Even if the cluster names are the same. I think one possible solution is to recreate the cluster with exact uuid + name but i haven't figured out yet, how to manually set the uuid. If I create the cluster via api, the **ClusterUuid** is set automatically - even if i try to change it.

Cheers Daniel

Answer (score 2):

We're currently rolling out a fix for this which should be global by EOD Friday. In the mean-time, be assured that your jobs are not actually running after the cluster has been deleted.

Comment: The Jobs are listed as "running". How do i check whether a job is running or not?

Comment: In this particular case, you could verify that the cluster was actually deleted by viewing the running VMs in your project. If there are none corresponding to your Dataproc cluster, then there is nowhere for the job to execute. Please also verify that your jobs are now showing their status as either ERROR or CANCELLED.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Jobs are on ERROR now.